# Is there a way to batch insert to multiple tables using psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following insert to multiple tables I want to do. Currently I am doing them sequentially like the following

```
    db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table1 ( \
                       my_foreign_id1, \
                       my_foreign_id2, \
                       some_meta_info1, \
                       some_meta_info2)  \
                 VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING *",
        (my_dict["my_foreign_id1"], 
         my_dict["my_foreign_id2"],
         my_dict["some_meta_info1"],
         my_dict["some_meta_info2"])
    )

    db_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO my_table2 ( \
                       my_foreign_id1, \
                       my_foreign_id2, \
                       some_note_info1, \
                       some_note_info2)  \
                 VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) RETURNING *",
        (my_dict["my_foreign_id1"], 
         my_dict["my_foreign_id2"],
         my_dict["some_note_info1"],
         my_dict["some_note_info2"])
    )
```

I want to do the insert above concurrently while ensuring that they are in one commit so that anyone fails I can just roll back.

Is there functionality in `psycopg2` that allow batch insert and not sequential insert?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default when you connect to your `postgresql` database and you start using a cursor, a transaction is opened. all the statements that you execute with the same cursor will be committed when you `cursor.commit()`. If they are not, your statements will be rolled back. So in your case either both of your statements will be committed or none.

Take a look at the documentation about the [transactions](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#transactions-control).